# How to rotate image view while not changing center X position

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to rotate my image view using following:

```
CGFloat degrees = -20.0f; //the value in degrees
    CGFloat radians = degrees * M_PI/180;
    _arrowImgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
```

It does rotate, but unfortunatelly it does rotate whole image moving it up. Please take a look at screenshots:

[image]

[image]

On second screenshot you can see that image is moved up and changed X coordinate. How to simply bend it like clock arrow?

UPDATED:
I changed code to:

```
self.arrowImgView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    CGFloat degrees = -20.0f; //the value in degrees
    CGFloat radians = degrees * M_PI/180;
    self.arrowImgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
```

[image]

Also i want to notice that i did set constraints like that :

```
 [_arrowImgView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.bottom.equalTo(self);
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.mas_centerX);
    }];
```

Comment: Have you checked that the position actually changed? Its hard to say from a screenshot, but it seems that it didn't actually move up - it may look like that, because of how your image looks.

Comment: @Losiowaty no i haven't. What do you mean?

Comment: Well, for one thing you can simply check the value of `_arrowImgView.center` before and after rotation.

Comment: @Losiowaty center x is not changed (it is 47 in my case).

Comment: And what about `center.y`?

Comment: @Losiowaty also not changed (23 in my case).

Comment: So, since we proved that the image didn't actually move, what is your question then?

Comment: @Losiowaty you have not seen my screenshots? I want effect like clock arrow. Instead, image rotating over it's own center position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
```

**Reference:** https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410817-anchorpoint

> Edit

I tried this below code in swift it works here

```
self.viewRotate.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    let degree : CGFloat = -20.0
    let rad : CGFloat = degree*CGFloat(M_PI/180)
    viewRotate.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rad)
```

**Output**

Before rotation

[image]

After rotation

[image]